# JRuby/tomcat 404 errors in rseponse to ajax GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby

This problem appears specific to routing for JRuby ajax requests. My page sends an ajax GET which works fine in rails development mode. When moved to tomcat via warbler, the **request is generated correctly**, but tomcat responds with a 404 error.

In other words, the line in routes.rb `get '/sector/method'` is sufficient that `http://localhost:3000/sector/method` is processed by Webrick, but if I change the port to 8080 (tomcat) I get a `HTTP status 404 The requested resource (/sector/method) is not available`.

Apparently tomcat needs to be told it is OK to process the GET even though there is no corresponding file to be found. Right? Fixes?

Thanks.

Comment: My routing rules in routes.rb are of the form `get 'sector/page'` which work in tomcat but become 'appname/sector/page` automatically. The ajax URL is coded in javascript as  `sector/methodname' which works with rails server, but unlike the routes which correspond to regular views, it is not automatically prefixed with appname when called, hence the 404. Is there an elegant way to fix this? An ugly kludge is to add another route.

Comment: What got me (tomcat novice) in trouble here was using the tomcat manager to deploy locally, which creates the appname subdirectory. On my real server I scp the .war to ROOT, which I THINK will eliminate the problem with the URL, so I have just been making trouble for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your request point to correct address? if application works, there is no way that  GETs does not. Please try to put the request directly into your browser and check...

Comment: You are correct that it is a problem in how the URL is constructed. The working URL for rails server is `http://sector/method` while tomcat wants the URL `http://appname/sector/method`.  Thanks. I should be able to work it out from here.